# VBA instead of hard coding mapping in vba code i want to refer to it in an excel sheet similar to a vlookup of if when functions

Tags: excel, vba

The second half with the for loop j variable is relevant to my question. You can see i have if then and case statements to output certain values. I want to know if there is an easy way to have this series of if then statements in an excel sheet that can be easily edited without going into the VBA code similar to a index match with multiple criteria.

```
    For Each wbv In Array(wb1, wb2)
    For Each ws In wbv.Worksheets
        If ws.name Like "*nvoice*" Then
            For i = 1 To lrowRetrieve
    
              If ws.Cells(i, "C").Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "C").Value <> 0 And ws.Cells(i, "G").Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "G").Value <> 0 Then
                  name = Trim(ws.Cells(i, "C").Value)
    
                If dict.Exists(name) = False Then
                  Set group = New clsgroup
                  group.name = name
                  dict.Add key:=group.name, Item:=group
                Else
                    Set group = dict(name)
                End If
    
                With group
                  .rate = .rate + ws.Cells(i, "H").Value
                  .volume = .volume + ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
                End With
              End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws
    Next wbv



For j = lrowLookupstart To lrowLookupend
        
            Select Case ws1.Cells(j, "H").Value
            Case "5455"
                If ws1.Cells(j, "K").Value = "Medical" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5455/5456").volume
                Else
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5455/5456 (non med)").volume
                End If
            Case "5457"
                If ws1.Cells(j, "K").Value = "Medical" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5457/5458").volume
                Else
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5457/5458 (non med)").volume
                End If
            Case "5747"
                ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5747/5794").volume
            Case "7065"
                If ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*nder 65*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("7065/7066").volume
                ElseIf ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*ver 65*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("7065/7066 65+").volume
                End If
            Case "7067"
                If ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*nder 65*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("7067/7068").volume
                ElseIf ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*ver 65*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("7067/7068 65+").volume
                End If
            Case "4841"
                If ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*nder 65*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4841 Enh").volume
                ElseIf ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*65-69*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4841 65+").volume
                ElseIf ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*70-74*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4841 70+").volume
                End If
            Case "4821"
                If ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*65-69*" Or ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*65 to 69*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4821 65+").volume
                ElseIf ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*70-74*" Or ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*70 to 74*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4821 70+").volume
                ElseIf ws1.Cells(j, "H").Value = "4821 75+" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4821 75+").volume
                ElseIf ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value = "4821 - Enhanced Plus OOCM" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4821 Enh").volume
                Else: ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4821").volume
                End If
            Case "4942"
                ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4942/5350").volume
            Case "4842"
                If ws1.Cells(j, "L").Value Like "*0-64*" Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4842").volume
                Else: ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4842 (non med)").volume
                End If
            Case "4972"
                ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4972/5350").volume
            Case "4973"
                ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("4973/5350").volume
            Case "5506"
                ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5506/5507").volume
            Case "5349"
                ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5339/5349").volume
            Case "5378"
                ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5377/5378").volume
            Case "5449"
                ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5449/5450").volume
    
            Case Else
                If dict.Exists(Trim(ws1.Cells(j, "H").Value)) = True Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict(Trim(ws1.Cells(j, "H").Value)).volume
                End If
    
            End Select
    Next j
```

the output value will be column M and will be based on conditions of values in columns H & L

[image: Table being altered]

Comment: You **definitly** should "outsource" these settings! Think of a configuration sheet - show us an example of it and how it comes into play - then we can help you. Without this information it is not possible.

Comment: This is very specific "business logic" - specific to you and your solution only. Each of the `Case` options has different value checks and results and actions. You may be able to find some common settings/actions to isolate in a function to call. You may be able to create an "action table", similar to the configuration sheet @Ike mentions. Overall, since this complexity is specific to your solution, streamlining may not be possible but isolating in functions may.

Comment: @Ike I have added an example for 4841

Comment: What we need to see, is the configuration of your if-then-else conditions. How did your boss explaied them when she gave you the task, how would you explain them to a trainee, whom you want to build the config table? That's where you have to start. And then come back with smaller programming tasks - and we can help you :-)

Comment: FYI you have `ElseIf ws1.Cells(j, "H").Value = "4821 75+" Then` in the `Case "4821"` block - that can never be True.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs are values from H, K and L - you need a table which maps those to a specific dictionary key.

Something like this should work - you'd loop over each row until you got a match, or if there's no match then run the `Case Else` from your `Select Case`.

[image]